# Dynamic user interface with r

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a dynamic user interface. I want nothing to be displayed when I select `"Total"`, not even an empty frame. I want something to be displayed only when I select `"Cancer"` or `" without cancer"`.

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamically generated user interface components"),
  fluidRow(
    
    column(3, wellPanel(
      selectInput("input_type", "Input type",
                  c("Total","Cancer", "Without cancer"
                  )
      )
    )),
    
    column(3, wellPanel(
      # This outputs the dynamic UI component
      uiOutput("ui")
    ))
  )
)







server<-function(input, output) {
  
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(input$input_type))
      return()
    
    # Depending on input$input_type, we'll generate a different
    # UI component and send it to the client.
    switch(input$input_type,
           "Cancer" = selectInput("dynamic", "Dynamic",
                                  choices = c("Lung cancer" = "Lung cancer",
                                              "Breast cancer" = "Breast cancer",
                                              "Colon cancer"=  "Colon cancer"),),
           "Without cancer" = selectInput("dynamic", "Dynamic",
                                  choices = c("Pneumonia" = "Pneumonia",
                                              "Gastro-enteritis" = "Gastro-enteritis",
                                              "Flu"=  "Flu"),)
    )
  })
  
  output$input_type_text <- renderText({
    input$input_type
  })
  
  output$dynamic_value <- renderPrint({
    str(input$dynamic)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `shinyjs::toggle()` to hide and show an element with a condition.

First add `{shinyjs}`, call `useShinyjs()` from within the `ui`, and add an `id` to the `wellPanel` you need to hide and show:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
ui<-fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Dynamically generated user interface components"),
  fluidRow(
    
    column(3, wellPanel(
      selectInput("input_type", "Input type",
                  c("Total","Cancer", "Without cancer"
                  )))),
    
    column(3, wellPanel( 
      id="wp",
      uiOutput("ui")
    ))
  )
)
```

Then add an `observe()` to trigger the `toggle()` the `wellPanel` whenever `input$input_type == "Total"`:

```r
server<-function(input, output) {
  observe(toggle(id = "wp", condition = input$input_type != "Total"))
  ...
```

Optionally you can also replace the `if()` with a `req()`:

```r
  output$ui <- renderUI({
    req( input$input_type != "Total")
    ...
```